# SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting the following error:

```
{ [SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'activityId' in 'field list']
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  message: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column \'activityId\' in \'field list\'',
  parent: 
   { [Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'activityId' in 'field list']
     code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
     errno: 1054,
     sqlState: '42S22',
     index: 0,
     sql: 'SELECT `id`, `activityType`, `customData`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `activityId` FROM `activitiesTemplates` AS `ActivitiesTemplate` WHERE `ActivitiesTemplate`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1;' },
  original: 
   { [Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'activityId' in 'field list']
     code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
     errno: 1054,
     sqlState: '42S22',
     index: 0,
     sql: 'SELECT `id`, `activityType`, `customData`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `activityId` FROM `activitiesTemplates` AS `ActivitiesTemplate` WHERE `ActivitiesTemplate`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1;' },
   sql: 'SELECT `id`, `activityType`, `customData`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `activityId` FROM `activitiesTemplates` AS `ActivitiesTemplate` WHERE `ActivitiesTemplate`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1;' },
```

Is this an error mySQL database/relationships? or somewhere in my Node.js code?

In the database table, I do not have a field name "`activityId`".  I also changed every instance in Code from `activityId` to `id` (a column that does exist in the table).

After making the changes I stopped my server.  I did `npm update`, and restarted the server ; however, the console logs the error above.

Comment: It is very difficult to speculate without seeing the models, associations and an example of a query that is similar to the error.

Comment: Models in the code don't have a column name 'activityId'.  Where do I find associations in code?

Comment: You have question: `or somewhere in my Node.js code?` , but there is no node.js code in your question, please provide related codes about the error. Can you share possible code blocks which can cause error.